# Sailsjs+Canvas send image into view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, sails.js, node-canvas

Right now im using sailsjs + Canvas, Im trying to send a canvas created in backend, to the browser into a view.

What i have done so far is creating a canvas in a controller and when you go to a route ex. /canvas it will show the image there. But how would i do if i want to send the canvas into a view? ex. homepage.ejs i understand that the backend dont have the html or document but could you not be able to send the element into a existing view?

I have tried looking at node-canvas browser.js example to make a script on the html to catch the canvas. but i could not make that work. So i need some help now.

**CanvasController**

```
module.exports = {

    myCanvasAction: function(req, res) {
    var { createCanvas } = require('canvas')
    var canvas = createCanvas(320, 320)
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 100);

    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png'),
    canvas.pngStream().pipe(res);
  }

};
```

**Route**

```
'GET /canvas': {
    controller: 'Canvas',
    action: 'myCanvasAction'
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for how its working with the non-ejs technique?